# Adding nested models based on javascript data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon gem to handle polygon map coordinates.

```
class Polygon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :coordinates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :coordinates
end

class Coordinate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :polygon_id
  belongs_to :polygon
end
```

I have a form which allows adding multiple coordinates to the polygon model and save it, it works manually.

Now I am using google maps drawing library to get the points on the map and I am stuck at how to invoke the cocoon to insert these points to the form on the page dynamically from the callback. The google maps sends 'overlaycomplete' event and in that callback, I have the full array of points.

How should I accomplish this ?

Comment: Is that your datamodel? Why not use postgis: it allows you to store geometries in the database. Retrieving a polygon in one go? That aside: if i understand correctly, you draw a polygon with google maps, so you have an array of points, and now you want to fill up a form? Why not just post the polygon and let the server side handle it?

Comment: Thanks, postGIS is on the todo list. Just wanted to try out a solution quickly. But I did eventually end up filling up the form in the maps callback. The reason for using the form is to allow the user to input some more fields before saving the polygon. It works as of now.